# Less: left: calc(50% - 38px);

Tags: css, less

How should we write in `.less` to obtain

```
left: calc(50% - 38px);
```

I have

```
@myWidth: 38px;
left: calc(50% - @myWidth);
```

I obtain

```
left: calc(12%); // ?? > (50-38) = 12%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS makes calculations using the first unit of measurement it encounters. Since you don't want LESS to calculate the expression, wrap it in a string.

[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meWRvm) - click view compiled in the CSS panel

```
left: calc(~'50% - 38px');

@myWidth: 38px;
left: calc(~'50% - @{myWidth}');
```